# How do I set a default value for an HStore field in a Ruby on Rails fixtures YAML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, yaml, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I am trying to use the [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) 4.0 HStore extension for [PostreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/). I would like to make one of my HStore fields required:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  validates :field_name, presence: true
  # ...
end
```

Being new to HStore, I generated a scaffold for Thing (`rails g scaffold Thing field_name:hstore`). Doing this my fixture file (`test/fixtures/things.yml`) did not include a default value for `field_name`:

```
one:
  # ...
  field_name:
  # ...
```

Which causes `rake test` to fail since there is no value provided for a required field.

**My question is: How do I set a value in my fixtures YAML file for `field_name` so that my tests will pass?**

So far I know:

1. This ***does not*** work:

   ```
   one:
     # ...
     field_name:
       small: 2
       medium: 5
       large: 4
     # ...
   ```
2. This also ***does not*** work:

   ```
   one:
     # ...
     field_name: {"small"=>"2", "medium"=>"5", "large"=>"4"}
     # ...
   ```

Thanks!

Comment: Did setting it the way I described work?

Comment: @derekyau No, there were syntax errors for the YAML file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am using Rails 4 and this is my fixture file, where options is a hstore field.

```
default:
  title: 'something'
  prefix: 'xxx'
  options: '"something"=>"2", ""=>"5"'
```

I couldn't find out how to properly use a Hash so I just hard coded it.

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty for having the only answer that works. While not elegant, it looks like there isn't a better way to do this yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Basically what you have to do is generate a hash in YAML

```
default:
  options:
    :something: 2
    :something_else: 3
```

Comment: Question - this seems to save the hash as a 'string', giving me the error `undefined method 'keys' for "{\"prompt\"=>\"Full name?\"}":String`. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: How are you parsing your yaml file? What you're getting is in JSON format.